# how to create button click event in gridview RowDataBound c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am trying to create button and click event in rowdatabound in gridview c# asp.net like below code

```
 protected void btnerror_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.RowDataBound += gv_RowDataBound;
        gv.RowCommand += gv_RowCommand;
        gv.RowCreated += gv_RowCreated;

        gv.EnableViewState = true;

        gv.DataSource = _dt;
        gv.DataBind();
}


void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        ImageButton btnUpdate = new ImageButton();

        btnUpdate.ID = "btnupdate";
        btnUpdate.ImageUrl = "~/SmartAdmin/Images/update.png";
        btnUpdate.ToolTip = "Click Update";
        btnUpdate.CommandName = "update";


        btnUpdate.Click += btnUpdate_Click;

        TableCell tc = new TableCell();

        tc.Controls.Add(btnUpdate);
        e.Row.Cells.Add(tc);

    }
}


void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "update")
    {

    }
}
```

while click that button click event is not firing ...

where i made error...

thank u.......

Comment: Do you really want to create the `GridView` manually? I strongly doubt that. Instead add it on the aspx and make it visible in `btnerror_Click`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really want to create the `GridView` manually? I strongly doubt that. Instead add it declaratively to the aspx-page and make it visible in `btnerror_Click`.

Don't create the control dynamically and register the event handler in `RowDataBound` but in `RowCreated` which is triggered on every postback (as opposed to `RowDataBound`):

```
void gv_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton btnUpdate = new ImageButton();
        btnUpdate.Click += btnUpdate_Click;
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();

        tc.Controls.Add(btnUpdate);
        e.Row.Cells.Add(tc);
    }
}

void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {    
        ImageButton btnUpdate = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControls("btnupdate") 
        btnUpdate.ID = "btnupdate";
        btnUpdate.ImageUrl = "~/SmartAdmin/Images/update.png";
        btnUpdate.ToolTip = "Click Update";
        btnUpdate.CommandName = "update";
    }
}
```

So create it in `RowCreated` but initialize it in `RowDataBound` where you can also access the datasource (if required).

Also note that you should `DataBind` the `GridView` only `if(!IsPostBack)` not on every postback (if that's the case). So add this check where you assign the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add function for click event

```
btnUpdate.Click += btnUpdate_Click;

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```