# How to fire click event of image button in datagridview in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am trying to use image button in datagridview with asp.
I have a dataset with some attachment file.
When datagridview is loading, check attachment files and add a imagebutton to download that files.
But Click event is not firing ..

I am using rowdatabound :

```
protected void GridViewOutputs_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.RowIndex);
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
        int SelectedActivityID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[8].Text);

        List<AttachedFile> attachedFiles = new List<AttachedFile>();
        attachedFiles = Check_SelectedIndex_Attachment(SelectedActivityID);

        string fileName = "None";
        int fileIndex = 1;
        foreach (AttachedFile currentFile in attachedFiles)
        {
            fileName = currentFile.Name;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileIndex + " : " + fileName);

            //ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtn");
            ImageButton imgbtn = new ImageButton();
            imgbtn.ID = "imgbtn" + fileIndex;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(imgbtn.ID.ToString());
            //imgbtn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(imgbtn_Command_Download);
            //imgbtn.Click += imgbtn_Click_Download;

            if (fileName.Contains("pdf"))
            {
                imgbtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/pdf icon.png";

            }
            else if (fileName.Contains(".doc"))
            {
                imgbtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/word icon.png";
            }
            else if (fileName.Contains(".ppt"))
            {
                imgbtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/powerpoint icon.png";
            }
            else if (fileName.Contains(".xls"))
            {
                imgbtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/excel icon.png";
            }
            else if (fileName.Contains(".vsd"))
            {
                imgbtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/visio icon.png";
            }

            imgbtn.CommandName = fileName;
            imgbtn.ToolTip = fileName;
            e.Row.Cells[9].Controls.Add(imgbtn);
            fileIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried rowCommand(Onrowcommand)

```
protected void RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //if button is clicked
    string commandName = e.CommandName;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(commandName);
    if (commandName == "Clicked")
    {
        //go find the index on the gridview
        int selectedIndex = GridViewOutputs.SelectedIndex;
        if (int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out selectedIndex))
        {
            //do something with database
        }
    }
    if (commandName.Contains("."))
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = commandName;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileName);
            FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
            AttachedFile file = fileManager.GetAttachedFileWithContentName(fileName);
            if (file.Bytes.Length > 0)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                Response.BinaryWrite(file.Bytes);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

I also tried Click event

```
private void imgbtn_Click_Download(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)(sender);
    string commandName = imgbtn.CommandName;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(commandName);
    if (commandName.Contains("."))
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = commandName;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileName);
            FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
            AttachedFile file = fileManager.GetAttachedFileWithContentName(fileName);
            if (file.Bytes.Length > 0)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                Response.BinaryWrite(file.Bytes);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

I also tried Command event

```
private void imgbtn_Command_Download(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string commandName = e.CommandName;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(commandName);
    if (commandName.Contains("."))
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = e.CommandName;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileName);
            FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
            AttachedFile file = fileManager.GetAttachedFileWithContentName(fileName);
            if (file.Bytes.Length > 0)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                Response.BinaryWrite(file.Bytes);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

Showing Imagebutton is worikng but when I click, I doesn't work.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please include the method where you call `GridViewOutputs.DataBind()`? I think you may be adding the event handler too late in the page's lifecycle.

Comment: Check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275641/how-to-create-button-click-event-in-gridview-rowdatabound-c-sharp-asp-net

Comment: You need to add the click event to the imgbtn which you commented off. You should uncomment it

Comment: @ShaiCohen DataBind() is in Page_Load Method.

Comment: @KwangsooJeon are you still looking for a solution to this?

Comment: @Shai Cohen I'm still looking for a solution